# How to process stderr in go?

Tags: go

I have an app called "myapp". That app simply writes to stderr.

The important bit is, I want to capture what is written in stderr and process it in real-time. How would I go about doing that?

I tried the code below. :

```
cmd := exec.Command("myapp") // this app prints lines to stderr
stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

if b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(stderr); err == nil {
    log.Println(string(b))
}                                                                                                       

if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

The code doesn't print out anyting.  I suspect it's because ioutil.ReadAll() is not the proper func to call since it waits for EOF. How else would I read from the stderr pipe?

You can replace the command executed with anything that outputs to stdout or stderr like `tail -f mylogfile`. The point is, I want to process the lines as they are written to stdout.

Comment: How are you trying to process it?

Comment: @iliacholy I plan to post each line to a REST API.

Comment: The way I did this is to actually use the bash | pipe and make the other application send a rest command for each line in input

Comment: @fabrizioM that's the correct way of doing it I think

Comment: @rexposadas cnicutar's solution is what you want then.

Comment: @fabrizioM +1 for the alternate solution. It might end up being the more elegant one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StderrPipe` returns a `ReadCloser`. You can use that to create a `bufio.Scanner` and then read lines one by one:

```
sc := bufio.NewScanner(stderr)
for sc.Scan() {
    fmt.Printf("Line: %s\n", sc.Text());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a type that implements [io.Writer](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) and set that as the [command's](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) stderr writer.

```
type Processor struct{}

func (Processor) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    // intercept data here
    return os.Stdout.Write(b)
}

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("mycommand")
    cmd.Stderr = Processor{}
    _ = cmd.Run()
}
```